# How to fix 404 error when communicate with API

Tags: javascript, laravel, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt.js *(frontend)* and laravel6 *(backend)* API. Laravel app is running  `http://172.16.10.86:8000` port and nuxt.js app is running `http://localhost:3000`. I want to send data in my MySQL database using nuxt.js app. When I send `POST` request from my nuxt.js app it redirects properly but does not insert any data in database. Inside network tab, I found a 404 error.

```
       methods:{
        async register(){
        try {
        await this.$axios.post('/auth/register',this.form);
        } catch(e) {
            return;
        }

            this.$auth.login({data: this.form});

            this.$router.push({name:'index'});
        }
```

nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
    strategies: { 
         local: { 
          endpoints:{
           login:{
      url: '/auth/login',method: 'post', propertyName: 'token'
    },
    user:{
      url:'me', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data'
    },
    logout:{
      url:'logout', method: 'get'
    }
  }
 } 
 },
 axios:{
   baseUrl:'http://172.16.10.86:8000/api'
 },
```

Comment: You know 404 means that the URL wasn't found?

Comment: thanks for your comment. where i made mistake ??

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your Network Tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just typo in your axios config.

It's should be `baseURL` not `baseUrl`. Please take a look at the [docs](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add full URL for the API server.

```
 methods:{
    async register() {
    try {
    await this.$axios.post('http://172.16.10.86:8000/api/auth/register', this.form);
    } catch(e) {
        return;
    }

        this.$auth.login({data: this.form});

        this.$router.push({name:'index'});
    }
```